# MVC3 Razor (Drop Down List)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new towards MVC3 Razor. Currently, I'm facing this error "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**", which I have no idea what is this about.

In Model

```
    public List<SelectListItem> CatList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string CatID { get; set; }
```

In Controller

```
    public ActionResult DisplayCategory()
    {
        var model = new CatModel();
        model.CatList = GetCat();
        return View(model);
    }


    private List<SelectListItem> GetCat()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> itemList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        itemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
        itemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
        return itemList;
    }
```

In CSHTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(c => c.CatID)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CatID, Model.CatList)</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace what you get? Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CategoryID, Model.CategoryTypeList) is giving the error

Comment: It also says NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.

Comment: What is `Model.CategoryTypeList`? In your posted code there is no sign of it... you only have `CatList`... please edit your question about `Model.CategoryTypeList` because the exception tells you that `Model.CategoryTypeList` is `null`

Comment: Opps, sorry I've posted the wrong one. It's @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CatID, Model.CatList).

Comment: I just put your code into a solution and it works just fine. I'm thinking something else is going on besides what you have shown here.

Comment: Could it be I missed out some reference? For the Controller, I have reference to model and for cshtml, I'm using @model Demo.Models.CatModel

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a POST action in which you forgot to reassign the `CatList` property of your view model so you are getting the NRE when you submit the form, not when the form is initially rendered:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCategory()
{
    var model = new CatModel();
    model.CatList = GetCat();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CatModel model)
{
    // some processing ...

    // since we return the same view we need to populate the CatList property
    // the same way we did in the GET action
    model.CatList = GetCat();
    return View(model);
}


private List<SelectListItem> GetCat()
{
    List<SelectListItem> itemList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    itemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
    itemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
    return itemList;
}
```