# MVC3 Drop Down List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, selectlistitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC3 Razor (Drop Down List)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437922/mvc3-razor-drop-down-list)

I've been getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Been trying to figure out this error for the past 12 hours. Hope someone can help.

This is causing the error.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CategoryID, Model.CategoryTypeList)
```

In SearchController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Demo.Models;

namespace Demo.Controllers
{
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Search/

    public ActionResult DisplayCategory()
    {
        var model = new SearchModel();
        model.CategoryTypeList = GetCategory();

        return View(model);
    }


    private List<SelectListItem> GetCategory()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
        return items;
    }

}
}
```

In SearchModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Demo.Controllers;

namespace Demo.Models
{
public class SearchModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> CategoryTypeList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }

}
}
```

In CSHTML

```
@model Demo.Models.SearchModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Search</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
<tr>
<td>@Html.LabelFor(c => c.CategoryID)</td>
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.CategoryID, Model.CategoryTypeList)</td>
</tr>

</table>
}
```

Stack Trace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
ASP._Page_Views_Home_Search_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\User_me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Demo\Demo\Views\Home\Search.cshtml:12
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +272
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +67
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +58
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +94
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +172
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +574
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +360
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +409
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +60
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +391
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +61
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +285
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +232
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +68
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +61
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +31
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +56
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +110
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: The fact that you reposted the exact same question doesn't change the fact that your code works just fine if copied and pasted into a blank MVC solution. There is something else going on here besides what you have posted, and we are going to need more information than what you have provided. The stack trace of the exception would be a good place to start.

Comment: How is this being called? Via an AJAX request, directly as a URL? As a partial rendered within another view?

Comment: its a partial rendered within another view

Comment: @user1673438 - Boom! There is your problem. A partial view rendered within another view doesn't inherit the Model context of it's parent. You have to pass it in via an overload. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470561(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I'm created the project as a internet application using Razor as the view engine. I've only create three files in the project, the SearchController, SearchModel and Search.cshtml

Comment: In this case, how do I solve the problem?...Sorry, because I'm totally new towards MVC3

Comment: @user1673438 - If you are calling it using RenderPartial, then your action method will never get executed. You need to call RenderAction if you want to actually execute the action, but make sure you aren't including a layout or you will get an entire page nested within another.

Comment: @user1673438 - Ok, see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry again, I'm getting more confused. Here is what I did, I created a new project using MVC3, and select the internet application instead of the empty one. I've also used Razor as the view engine. I've create only three files, the SearchController, SearchModel, Search.cshtml. Everything else is in default, provided by VS2010. I've no clue on the structure of the created project. So is Html.RenderAction the problem I'm facing? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @user1673438 - Did you try to use RenderAction in your previous solution?

Comment: Can I upload the files and so that you can take a look? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1673438 - Sure, if you give me a link I can take a look.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?pj6ufg89doqe8b5 thank you.

Comment: @user1673438 - Ok, I've modified the .csproj to demonstrate how you should have things structured. Hopefully it all makes sense. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36924409/Practical_5.zip

Comment: Great...thanks..Looking at the structure, I've fully understand how it works now. Last question, there are three extra tabs appears inside, is it due to the search.cshtml file?

Comment: Yup, I've got it...Thanks for your patience...

Comment: @user1673438 - No problem man. Glad you are up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comments above, if you want to call this as a seperate unit within another page, then you will need to either pass the model in using Html.RenderPartial, or call Html.RenderAction in order to execute the entire action and output the resulting HTML.

**Using [Html.RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**

```
@*
   Assuming that you have already initialized some variable
   called 'mySearchModel'
*@

@Html.RenderPartial("DisplayCategory", mySearchModel)
```

This will ensure that the Model property on the view gets set.

**Using [Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)**

```
//Slight change to your action method to ensure it returns
// a partial view, and will only ever be called as a child
// action of another action.
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult DisplayCategory()
{
    var model = new SearchModel();
    model.CategoryTypeList = GetCategory();

    return PartialView(model);
}


@Html.RenderAction("DisplayCategory")
```

Further reading:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx
http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx